# Call the perl script by batch script at every day at 5 minutes interval

Tags: batch-file

I want to run my perl script<" ftp_files_copy.pl"> on windows through batch file<"Run_perl_script.bat"> at every 5 minutes interval
Well I have written one batch script:

```
schtasks /create /tn "batch Script" /tr E:\script\Run_perl_script.bat /sc minute /mo 5 
perl ftp_files_copy.pl
```

But the problem is every 5 minutes command prompt displays for a while and then disappears  but nothing is happening i mean my perl script is not running

These is my first batch script so please guys just help me out from this problem

Thanks

Comment: where's the ftp_files_copy.pl located?

Comment: both are on my local system and are in same folder i.e E:\script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you need to specify the full path to your `ftp_files_copy.pl` script:

```
schtasks /create /tn "batch Script" /tr E:\script\Run_perl_script.bat /sc minute /mo 5 
perl E:\script\ftp_files_copy.pl
```

because, when the script is invoked, the `script` directory is not necessarily (in fact, unlikely) the current working directory, and so the `perl` interpreter needs to know the exact path to the script.

Comment: when i tried your suggested code i got error: Invalid syntax.
type ""SCHTASKS /?

Comment: @user1202644: I wonder... I didn't change the first line, having assumed it was working fine.

Comment: well i had added in first few things like \s \u \p .but i don't think  that will create any prob .Apart from system name i have user name and password thats what i had changed :(

Comment: @user1202644: Just in case: you meant `/s … /u … /p …` actually, *not* `\s … \u … \p …`, right?